# How the App get the notification from APNS when it open

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

After the iphone have the notification from APNS,we open the app, how the app get the message from notification 
  Firstly, I think the system will storage the message in notification, But after I have try something, I don't think so . Is it send the request to APNS again when we open the App?
(I have a try in QQ is that after get the notification from APNS ,I disconnect the Internet ,and then I open the App but I cann't get the new message in QQ)

[get notification with connecting the Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBOpB.jpg)

[disconnect before open QQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMcYK.jpg)

After get the notification, I didn't tap on it. And disconnect the Internet .Then open the QQ. But QQ didn't get the message -- "hello7" what have sent by notification defore.

Comment: what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: when the notification is sent to my iphone, Will my iOS system  stroage the message in notification in some place?

Comment: Notification Center stores the data locally. whenever you tap on notification, it sends the data to your app.

Comment: If I didn't tap on the notification, will the data be stored?

Comment: If you received notification then your device have data. It does not matter if you tapped on notification or not.

Answer (score 0):

System call didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate method when the device receives any push notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;            

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {                
        // Nothing to do if applicationState is Inactive, the iOS already displayed an alert view.                
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your App name received this notification while it was running:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];          
    }    
}
```

Comment: I know that. What I want to ask is that the how to get the useInfo? Is it send the request to APNS to get it? Or get it form the storage?(When I disconnect the Internet before I open the App.I didn't get the new message )